# Variation in prediction length and test data length while using predict_generator

Tags: time-series, generator

```
df = pd.read_csv('F:/series.csv')

train, validate, test = df[0:60], df[60:80], df[80:100]

sc = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (-1, 1))

train = sc.fit_transform(train)

validate = sc.fit_transform(validate)

test = sc.fit_transform(test)


train = train.reshape((len(train),1))

test = test.reshape((len(test),1))

validate = validate.reshape((len(validate),1))

n_input = 5

n_features = 1

generator_train = TimeseriesGenerator(train, train, length=n_input, batch_size=2)

generator_validate = TimeseriesGenerator(validate, validate, length=n_input, batch_size=2)

generator_test = TimeseriesGenerator(test, test, length=n_input, batch_size=2)

model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(200, return_sequences = True,  input_shape=(n_input, n_features)))

model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(LSTM(200))

model.add(Dense(units = 1))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

history = model.fit_generator(generator_train, epochs= 100, validation_data = generator_validate)

model.evaluate_generator(generator_test)

prediction = model.predict_generator(generator_test, steps = 5)

prediction.shape
(10,1)

test.shape
(20,1)
```

This confuses me, How to solve the problem? How to evaluate the predicted and test data? Whats the mistake I am making?

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer, the predict generator length depends on length of (test_generator*batch_size). Now to measure RMSE eliminate the first n_input length of test data. Now the size becomes equal.